# Horizontally Align Position Fixed Div

Tags: css

I've read a lot of the options on here to achieve this but for some reason i can't get anything to work the way i want it.

I'm trying to get a countdown timer to always stay horizontally centered. The problem is that because it changes ever so slightly with every second countdown i need it to have a position fixed, otherwise the start numbers jump left and right a little bit as the last number changes fractionally in size between different numbers .. Make sense ?

So giving it a fixed position allows the numbers to change smoothly, however it makes it very difficult to center perfectly, as once again the width changes depending on where the counter is set.

I've set up a little JSFiddle if anybody would be so kind as to take a look.

Greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>MATRIX</h1></a>
    </nav>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="countdown"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8pmoxxr/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
div#countdown {
    left: 50%; /* move #countdown's left edge to center */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* shift #countdown to the left by half of it's width */
    white-space: nowrap; /* keep #countdown from word-breaking */
}
```

```js
// set the date we're counting down to
            var target_date = new Date('Dec, 25, 2016').getTime();

            // variables for time units
            var days, hours, minutes, seconds, ms_step = 10;

            // get tag element
            var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');

            setInterval(function () {
                var current_date = new Date().getTime();
                var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;
                days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
                seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;
                hours = parseInt(seconds_left / 3600);
                hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
                seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;
                min = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
                min = min < 10 ? '0' + min : min;
                sec = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
                sec = sec < 10 ? '0' + sec : sec;
                ms = parseInt(target_date - current_date);

                // format countdown string + set tag value
                countdown.innerHTML = '' +
                        '<span class="days">' + days + ': </span>' +
                        '<span class="hours">' + hours + ': </span>' +
                        '<span class="minutes">' + min + ': </span>' +
                        '<span class="seconds">' + sec + '</span>';
                // this is just for milliseconds only
                /* countdown.innerHTML = 
                 '<span class="ms">'+ms+' ms</span>'; */
            }, ms_step);
```

```css
html {
    background: url(../images/main_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/main_bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/main_bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
  background-color: lightgray;
}

html:after {
    content: "";
    background: url(../images/overlay.png) repeat;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}

body{
    background-color : transparent;
    height:100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.navbar {
    min-height : 90px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
    font-size : 36px;
    font-weight : 200;
    margin: 0px;
    color : #000;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    z-index:3;
}

.container {
    height:100%;
}
div#countdown {
    position: fixed;
    top: 230px;
    left: 50%; /* move element's left edge to center */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* shift element to the left by half of it's width */
    white-space: nowrap; /* keep countdown from word-breaking */
}
#countdown span {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

#countdown span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>MATRIX</h1></a>
</nav>


<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the easiest solution to that issue is to concatenate a leading zero to the units if less than 10.  I updated the JS in my snippet to so.  Also, using a monospace font would help keep width stable.  Otherwise, you can come up with some JavaScript to check positioning of element on each tick of countdown.

Comment: That my dear friend, achieved the perfect result !

Comment: Also found a nice monospace font Roboto Mono, perfect result thank you kindly !